# How to sed, awk, or tr certain characters in certain situations?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

How could I awk, sed or tr a `" "` and replace it with a `","`. More specifically when the number of fields for each line are different. I know how to simply sed the problem

```
sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Here's and example of a problem

```
Ted 36 Shaker Heights 04-25-1978
Robin 34 Vancouver 07-23-1980
Marshall 36 St. Cloud 11-28-1978
Lily 37 New York 03-22-1978
```

I need to sed, awk, or tr so the result becomes

```
Ted,36,Shaker Heights,04-25-1978
Robin,34,Vancouver,07-23-1980
Marshall,36,St. Cloud,11-28-1978
Lily,37,New York,03-22-1978
```

I am having trouble with the space within the city name. Any suggestions on how to fix that? The field numbers for each line is not always consist. It will either have 4 or 5 depending on the city.

Comment: if it is not always the same, show some sample input in which this happens

Comment: I did. 3 lines have 5 fields, 1 line (the 2nd line)  has 4 fields. It will always be name, age, city, date of birth.

Comment: So the goal is to replace the first, second, and last space with commas, is that correct? Or can spaces also appear in another field?

Comment: @Wintermute I guess spaces could appear in the name. Like if someones name was Ann Marie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the city is always surrounded by numbers, you can just check for the transition from digits to non-digits or vice versa:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([^0-9]\)/\1,\2/g;s/\([^0-9]\) \([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g'
```

Comment: Wow that's a great solution would have never of thought to do that! Just for further reference, how would you go about doing this if there were no numbers surrounding the city?

Comment: If the city is still the only multiword column, you can count spaces from the left and from the right. If two multiword columns come together, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]+) /,\1,/;s/ ([0-9-]+)$/,\1/' file
```

Output:

```
Ted,36,Shaker Heights,04-25-1978
Robin,34,Vancouver,07-23-1980
Marshall,36,St. Cloud,11-28-1978
Lily,37,New York,03-22-1978
```

Answer (score 1):

a dumb and basic approach that uses the greediness:

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]*) ([0-9]*) (.*) /\1,\2,\3,/' file
```

or shorter:

```
sed -r 's/ ([0-9]*) (.*) /,\1,\2,/' file
```